# Spring OAuth2 oauth/token Simple Implementation Gives Always 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have tried to implement and understand oauth2 in spring boot but even in simple implementations with inMemory() and inMemoryAuthentication() like this I always get 401 unauthorized in oauth/token. Could someone please help me? I'm already losing hope hehe

Currently using **Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE**

AuthorizationConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfigurations extends AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
          .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
          .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer client) throws Exception {
        client.inMemory().withClient("client")
        .secret("secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","authorization_code", "refresh_token")
        .scopes("read");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoint) throws Exception {
        endpoint.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
      throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("john").password(passwordEncoder().encode("123")).roles("USER");
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() 
      throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm sending in Postman or Insomnia the following request:

In basic authorization:

> USERNAME=client PASSWORD=secret

In body (form):

> grant_type= password username=john password=123

and receive

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-02-29T04:26:43.930+0000",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

Comment: Where is your `ResourceServer` Configuration? You must need a ResourceServer that'll validate the access token from authorization server and send you response after authentication ...

Comment: If you're a beginner then please start with spring oauth2 [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/). There are plenty of examples on the internet with password grant. Check them out!